# MergeSort Recursion

Tags: algorithm, c++11, recursion

```
// main function 
void mergeSort(int input[],int size){ // 
    if(size == 0 || size == 1) return;  //base case
    int m = size/2; //finding the mid 
    mergeSort(helper(input,0,m),m);  //left array
    mergeSort(helper(input,m,size),size-m);  // right array
    merge(input,0,m,size); // merging the both arrays
}

void merge(int *input,int start,int size1,int size) //merging array in increasing order
{
    int a[size];
    int i=start,j=size1,k=0;
    while(i < size1 && j < size){
        if(input[i] < input[j]){
            a[k++] = input[i++];
        }
        else{
            a[k++] = input[j++];
        }
    }
    while(i < size1){
        a[k++] = input[i++];
    }
    while(j < size){
        a[k++] = input[j++];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        input[i] = a[i];
    }
}
int* helper(int input[],int s,int e){// this function helps get the half array
    int a[e-s];
    for(int i=s,j=0;i<e;i++,j++){
        a[j] = input[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<e-s;i++){
        input[i] = a[i];
    }
    return input;
}
```

I am not able to debugg this code
can anybody tell me why this is not right
I divide the two half with the help of **helper** function and then pass it to the **merge** to get the output

Comment: Does the split work? Does the merge work? Where exactly does your code something different than you expected? You can check this with printf-debugging and pen and paper.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete merge-sort algorithm.

First, define a function that splits a given array into two subarrays, then merges them back sorted.

```
void merge(int *array, int start, int mid, int end)
{
    // 1. Split array into two subarrays: left and right
    const int left_size = mid - start + 1;
    const int right_size = end - mid;

    int left_subarray[left_size];
    int right_subarray[right_size];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < left_size; i++)
        left_subarray[i] = array[start + i];

    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < right_size; j++)
        right_subarray[j] = array[mid + 1 + j];

    // 2. Merge them sorted into array
    i = 0; j = 0;
    int k;
    for (k = start; i < left_size && j < right_size; k++) {
        if (left_subarray[i] <= right_subarray[j])
            array[k] = left_subarray[i++];
        else
            array[k] = right_subarray[j++];
    
    }

    for (; i < left_size; i++)
        array[k++] = left_subarray[i];

    for (; j < right_size; j++)
        array[k++] = right_subarray[j];
}
```

The first part of `merge()` explains how you can split an array into two subarrays. Now you can use recursion to merge-sort the array:

```
void merge_sort(int *array, int start, int end)
{
    if (start >= end)
        return;

    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

    merge_sort(array, start, mid);
    merge_sort(array, mid + 1, end);

    merge(array, start, mid, end);
}
```

You can define a function to help you print arrays:

```
void print_array(int *array, int size, const char *sep)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d%s", array[i], sep);

    printf("\n");
}
```

Here's an example program:

```
int main()
{
    int array[] = {9, 6, 8, 7, 5, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1};
    const int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);

    printf("Unsorted array:\t");
    print_array(array, size, " ");
    
    merge_sort(array, 0, size-1);
    
    printf("Sorted array:\t");
    print_array(array, size, " ");
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you could explain what the main issues were in the Asker's code. It will be more of help to them, as they could have found a working implementation any way.

Comment: @trincot A lot of issues. `helper()` is modifying the original array. He should create a new one and split it in two. Also, as he wrote it, he needs to do it dynamically so he can return it. The compiler is throwing some implicit declaration warnings. I thought it would be better to write the code from scratch.

Comment: I mean: edit your question, and explain this in your answer.